# SKLearn warning "valid feature names" in version 1.0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following warning after upgrading to version 1.0 of scikit-learn:

> UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but IsolationForest was
> fitted with feature name

I cannot find in the docs on what is a "valid feature name". How do I deal with this warning?

Comment: Could you provide the feature names you used when training it? My guess is that there are spaces or capital letters.

Comment: Yes, there are capital letters, underscores and points, like '^back_2_PCA_3.3'. I will try to get rid of them, but some of them are keys in other python dicts. Thank you

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example? I have experienced the same issue, but it is through a combination of sklearn, pandas, and shap.

Comment: I am getting the same warning with sklearn IsolationForest. My feature names contain no special characters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 136):

I got the same warning message with another sklearn model. I realized that it was showing up because I fitted the model with a data in a dataframe, and then used only the values to predict. From the moment I fixed that, the warning disappeared.

Here is an example:

```
model_reg.fit(scaled_x_train, y_train[vp].values)
data_pred = model_reg.predict(scaled_x_test.values)
```

This first code had the warning, because `scaled_x_train` is a DataFrame with feature names, while `scaled_x_test.values` is only values, without feature names. Then, I changed to this:

```
model_reg.fit(scaled_x_train.values, y_train[vp].values)
data_pred = model_reg.predict(scaled_x_test.values)
```

And now there are no more warnings on my code.

Comment: Could you explain whether fitting the dataframe and values make any difference in prediction?

Comment: @Coder Sci-kit-Learn needs i/p (training set), and o/p data set as arguments when fitting them. Inserting these as data-frame with header/feature or just values (i.e., multi-dimensional arrays) will NOT make any difference. The difference might occur  only if the features selected when loading the values are not corresponding to the specific training or output/testing data set.

Comment: got same issue, `x.values` fixed my problem.

Comment: model.fit(X.values, y) solved my problem (instead of model.fit(X, y)).

Answer (score 34):

I was getting very similar error but on module DecisionTreeClassifier for `Fit` and `Predict`.

Initially I was sending dataframe as input to fit with headers and I got the error.

When I trimmed to remove the headers and sent only values then the error got disappeared.
Sample code before and after changes.

Code with Warning:

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(x,y)  #Here x includes the dataframe with headers
predictions = model.predict([
    [20,1], [20,0]
])
print(predictions)
```

Code without Warning:

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(x.values,y)  #Here x.values will have only values without headers
predictions = model.predict([
     [20,1], [20,0]
])
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! But why `y.values` is not there?

Comment: @MRUNALMUNOT y.values may not be required if the y terms are already only having values stored in them. Example: y = music_data["genre"] , then the y may contain only values like HipHop Jazz Acoustic Classical. Note that the output data y only contains values with Name: genre, dtype: object. Hence, it may not be necessary to unpack y.

Comment: This solution worked for me, although it throws the error when the `.fit` is called instead. However, as fit only happens once whereas predict might be run across a DataFrame of rows, one warning is far preferable.

Answer (score 18):

I had also the same problem .The problem was due to fact that I fitted the model with X train data as dataframe (`model.fit(X,Y)`) and I make a prediction with with X test as an array ( `model.predict([ [20,0] ])` ) . To solve that I have converted the X train dataframe into an array as illustrated bellow .

**BEFORE**

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,Y) # X train here is a dataFrame
predictions = model.predict([20,0])  ## generates warning
```

**AFTER**

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
X = X.values # conversion of X  into array
model.fit(X,Y)
model.predict([ [20,0] ])  #now ok , no warning
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works like a charm..!! And there is no need to bypass any error again.

Comment: My `scikit-learn` version is 1.2.2 and I am getting the same kind of warning `UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but DecisionTreeClassifier was fitted with feature names`. `X.values` fixes the warning. It would be great if we could use X.values & Y.values, which would make it similar to a numpy array.

Answer (score 15):

The other answers so far recommend (re)training using a numpy array instead of a dataframe for the training data.  The warning is a sort of safety feature, to ensure you're passing the data you meant to, so I would suggest to pass a dataframe (with correct column labels!) to the `predict` function instead, e.g.:

```py
test_row = pd.Dataframe({
    "<feat1_name>": [20],
    "<feat2_name>": [0],
})
model.predict(test_row)
```

Also, note that it's just a warning, not an error.  You can ignore the warning and proceed with the rest of your code without problem; just be sure that the data is in the same order as it was trained with!

Comment: It seems there's a fix related to a spurious warning: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/25931

Answer (score 3):

Everyone seems to be suggesting `.values`; however, say, you don't want to modify your training process or someone just sent you the *pickle* `.pkl` file for you to work with.

What you can do is to re-create a valid Pandas dataframe as it was with the training/fitting. e.g.

```py
# features here is just a list
df = pandas.DataFrame([features])
df.columns = ["provide", "the", "list", "of", "feature names", "in", "order"]
prediction = model.predict(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error while using dataframes but by passing only values it is no more there

use

```
reg = reg.predict( x[['data']].values , y)
```

It is showing error because our dataframe has feature names but we should fit the data as 2d array(or matrix) with values for training or testing the dataset.

Here is the image of the same thing mentioned above [image of jupytr notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHHVT.png)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest also adding y.values to regression.fit() method, because if we are

In my example, I have a csv with three data points like so,
Car,Model,Volume,Weight,CO2
Toyoty,Aygo,1000,790,99
Mitsubishi,Space Star,1200,1160,95

Based on an example, I am trying to find out how much CO2 a car produces based on its volume of engine and weight.
So,

```py
X = df[['Weight', 'Volume']]
y = df['CO2']
#python
regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# regression.fit(X, y) this gave some errors
regression.fit(X.values, y.values) # This did not give any errors
```

The reason being grabbing the values will ignore the first line of csv data, i.e the title.