# sklearn scaler train with feature names but use on no names feature, this is ok?

Tags: scikit-learn

I use sklearn scaller (power transform and more) who were train on feature with names column in a data frame.
I reuse this scaller on a new data set, with same order columns but no names.
It is ok? I imagine yes if the order stay the same...

since I've got this warnning...

```
UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but PowerTransformer 
was fitted with feature names
  "X does not have valid feature names, but"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SKLearn warnings in version 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326639/sklearn-warnings-in-version-1-0)

Comment: @BenReiniger although certainly relevant (and possibly helpful), OP here seems to ask a different thing, i.e. if it is OK to ignore the warning provided that they have kept the same feature order, which no other answer there (except [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70186785/4685471)) seems to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up Date and Answer:
The order is kept and the warning can be ignore.
Thanks to @Ben Reiniger for the ref,