# DecisionTreeRegressor isnt using my x variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm using the pandas library and using sklearn for the DecisionTreeRegressor, I imported a CSV file that I'm using and it has data on different bikes, the columns that I need are model_year,kms_driven, owner(which is the number of owners), price,and power.

while fiting the DecisionTreeRegressor() to the CSV and trying to make it predict the price of a bike model_year=2015, kms driven 30000 and 1 owner it gives me the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:451: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but DecisionTreeRegressor was fitted with feature names
  "X does not have valid feature names, but"
```

here is my code

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
# read the data file and create two data arrays

# cleaned dataset without hp (horsepower)
df1 = pd.read_csv("/content/KMS_bikes_cleaned.csv")

# cleaned dataset without kms (kilometers driven)
df2 = pd.read_csv("/content/POWER_bikes_cleaned.csv")

# print the df1 and df2 data arrays
print(df1)
print(df1)
```

output:

```
 model_year  kms_driven  owner   price
0           1970        5000      3  190000
1           1986        8990      2  100000
2           1986       50000      3  110000
3           1990       32000      2   63750
4           1990       13031      3  100000
...          ...         ...    ...     ...
5598        2021        2700      1  155600
5599        2021        3000      1  160000
5600        2021         850      2   70000
5601        2021         100      1  300000
5602        2021        7200      1  195400

[5603 rows x 4 columns]
      model_year  kms_driven  owner   price
0           1970        5000      3  190000
1           1986        8990      2  100000
2           1986       50000      3  110000
3           1990       32000      2   63750
4           1990       13031      3  100000
...          ...         ...    ...     ...
5598        2021        2700      1  155600
5599        2021        3000      1  160000
5600        2021         850      2   70000
5601        2021         100      1  300000
5602        2021        7200      1  195400

# select predictors
X1 = df1.drop(columns='price')
Y1 = df1 ['price']
# print the X1 and Y2 variables
print(X1)
print(Y1)
```

output:

```
 model_year  kms_driven  owner
0           1970        5000      3
1           1986        8990      2
2           1986       50000      3
3           1990       32000      2
4           1990       13031      3
...          ...         ...    ...
5598        2021        2700      1
5599        2021        3000      1
5600        2021         850      2
5601        2021         100      1
5602        2021        7200      1

[5603 rows x 3 columns]
0       190000
1       100000
2       110000
3        63750
4       100000
         ...  
5598    155600
5599    160000
5600     70000
5601    300000
5602    195400
Name: price, Length: 5603, dtype: int64

# name model
model1 = DecisionTreeRegressor()
# fit the model into all of the data
model1.fit (X1,Y1)
# predicted price of a 2015 bike driven 30,000 km sold by its first owner
predict1 = model1.predict ([[2015, 30000, 1]])
#print predict1
print(predict1)



# select predictors
X2 = df2.drop(columns="price")
Y2 = df2["price"]
# print the X and Y variables
print(X2)
print(Y2)

model_year  owner  power
0           1970      3  19.80
1           1986      2  19.80
2           1986      3  19.80
3           1990      2  11.00
4           1990      3  19.80
...          ...    ...    ...
5598        2021      1  14.30
5599        2021      1  14.50
5600        2021      2  10.72
5601        2021      1  30.00
5602        2021      1  19.10

[5603 rows x 3 columns]
0       190000
1       100000
2       110000
3        63750
4       100000
         ...  
5598    155600
5599    160000
5600     70000
5601    300000
5602    195400
Name: price, Length: 5603, dtype: int64

# name model
model2 = DecisionTreeRegressor()
# fit the model into all of the data
model2.fit (X2,Y2)
# predicted price of a 2018 bike with 50 bph sold by its second owner
output2 = model2.predict ([[2018, 2, 50.0]])
#print output2
print(output2)
```

output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:451: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but DecisionTreeRegressor was fitted with feature names
  "X does not have valid feature names, but"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SKLearn warning "valid feature names" in version 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326639/sklearn-warning-valid-feature-names-in-version-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

To customize my answer to the proposed duplicate: pass the new data to predict on as a dataframe:

```py
test1 = pd.Dataframe({
    "model_year": 2015,
    "kms_driven": 30000,
    "owner": 1,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I could not reproduce the warning message, but I found a similar question here: [SKLearn warning "valid feature names" in version 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326639/sklearn-warning-valid-feature-names-in-version-1-0)

It seems like this problem is specific to version 1.0. (I'm still using 0.24.2).

If you pass the values of the dataframe, there should be no more warnings.

```
model2.fit(X2.values, Y2)
```