# X does not have valid feature names, but RFECV was fitted with feature names

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wrote this code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest 
#from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, recall_score, accuracy_score, precision_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer 
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,recall_score,f1_score,roc_auc_score 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification 
from numpy import mean 
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import std 
from sklearn.utils import shuffle 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import joblib
import shap

df = pd.read_csv('train.txt',sep='\t')


def create_model(X_train=full_X_train,y_train=full_y_train,model_name=SVC(kernel='linear'),n_splits=5,file_name='random_forest_with_hpo_with_fs_all_features_class'):


      clf = model_name 
      k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits,random_state=42,shuffle=True) 
      f1 = [] 
      count = 0 
      for train_index,test_index in k_fold.split(X_train,y_train): 
            x_train_fold,x_test_fold = X_train.iloc[train_index],X_train.iloc[test_index] 
            y_train_fold,y_test_fold = y_train[train_index],y_train[test_index] 
            clf.fit(x_train_fold,y_train_fold) 
            y_pred = clf.predict(x_test_fold) 
            save_mod = file_name + '.' + str(count) + '.fold.json' 
            pickle.dump(clf,open(save_mod,'wb')) 
  
            f1.append(f1_score(y_test_fold,y_pred)) 
      return f1



def run_model_with_grid_search(model_name=RandomForestClassifier(),X_train=full_X_train,y_train=full_y_train,model_id='random_forest_with_hpo_with_fs_all_features_class', n_splits=5, output_file='random_forest_with_hpo_with_fs_all_features_class.txt', param_grid={}): 

      param_grid = [{'random_forest_with_hpo_with_fs_all_features_class__bootstrap':[True,False],
                     'random_forest_with_hpo_with_fs_all_features_class__max_depth':[10,20,30,40],
                     'random_forest_with_hpo_with_fs_all_features_class__n_estimators':[200,500,700]                       
      }]
 

      pipe = Pipeline([('feature_selection',RFECV(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(),scoring='accuracy',step=1,cv=StratifiedKFold(5))),('random_forest_with_hpo_with_fs_all_features_class',RandomForestClassifier())])

      search = GridSearchCV( 
        pipe,
        cv=5,
        param_grid=param_grid,
        scoring='accuracy',
        refit=True
        ) 
      fit_model = search.fit(X_train,y_train)
      print('Optimal number of features: ' + feature_selection.n_features_) 
      return fit_model,fit_model.best_params_,fit_model.best_score_


fit_model,params,best_score = run_model_with_grid_search()
model = create_model(model_name=fit_model)
```

I get the warning 'X does not have valid feature names, but RFECV was fitted with feature names'. I can see this question elsewhere e.g.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326639/sklearn-warning-valid-feature-names-in-version-1-0) but I can't understand how this answer would apply here - could someone point out where in the code below is leading to this warning (and I guess ideally how to fix it).

Comment: What version of sklearn do you have?  When feature name checking was first put in place, there were a handful of bugs with specific (often ensemble/meta) estimators.  Running your code (with tweaks to make it run, to use an sklearn dataset, and to run faster; please always provide a minimal reproducible example) in sklearn v1.1.1, I get no warnings.

Comment: Thanks, so I have v.1.0.1 but I'm in a colab and using their server where it's difficult to get new versions of software installed, so I"m wondering would it be possible to see what worked for you, to see if I can get that to work for me before I reach out to the sys admins for new versions of sklearn?

Comment: My tweaks were: you haven't defined `feature_selection` used in `run_model_with_grid_search`, so I replaced it with `search.best_estimator_['feature_selection']`; I removed several of the hyperparameter options; I reduced the number of folds in cross-validations; I used the breast cancer sklearn dataset. // likely the issue was resolved at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/21578/files#diff-c6c2db6c2fe3fd4325496252937b7a3c08ebdffc7c0546bce69e4508f2ba3a6b

Comment: Thank you for the link. Could I ask about the  ```search.best_estimator_['feature_selection']``` like where specifically you changed it? Because I had as part of my pipeline```pipe = Pipeline([('feature_selection',RFECV(estimator=RandomForestClassifier()```, I thought I had (but I am 100% certain that you know more), so I'm just confused where I was meant to change to incorporate ```search.best_estimator_['feature_selection']```; thanks.

Comment: in the print statement

Comment: Thank you so much. Could I ask, just changing what's in the print statement won't matter to what the actual function is doing, so when you say: you haven't defined ```feature_selection``` used in ```run_model_with_grid_search```, so I replaced it with ```search.best_estimator_['feature_selection']```....I think I'm mis-understanding where you changed it so that the feature selection is actually done properly (aside from the print statement which won't matter)? Also, let me know if you rather I asked this as a new question?