# Is there a reason I am receiving a UserWarning in LogisticRegression that says that my X variable doesn't have valid feature names?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


df = pd.read_csv("/Users/aahan/Desktop/diabetes_prediction_dataset.csv")

df_e = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ["gender", "smoking_history"])

df_e.rename(columns={"smoking_history_No Info": "smoking_history_No_Info"}, inplace = True)
df_e.rename(columns={"smoking_history_not current": "smoking_history_not_current"}, inplace = True)


X=df_e.drop(["diabetes"], axis=1)

Y=df_e["diabetes"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,train_size = 0.8, random_state=42)

model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 2000)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model.predict([[87, 0, 1, 26, 6.9, 100, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]))
```

Here is my X variable's feature

```
 names: 'age', 'hypertension', 'heart_disease', 'bmi', 'HbA1c_level',
       'blood_glucose_level', 'gender_Female', 'gender_Male', 'gender_Other',
       'smoking_history_No_Info', 'smoking_history_current',
       'smoking_history_ever', 'smoking_history_former',
       'smoking_history_never', 'smoking_history_not_current'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SKLearn warning "valid feature names" in version 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326639/sklearn-warning-valid-feature-names-in-version-1-0)

Answer (score 1):

You should check similar questions like: [SKLearn warning "valid feature names" in version 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326639/sklearn-warning-valid-feature-names-in-version-1-0)

You are training the model with dataframe headers but predicting on an array.

To make the warning disappear you could either train on an array, e.g.

```py
X=df_e.drop(["diabetes"], axis=1).values
```

or pass a header when you predict a sample too

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, you should vote to close as such, not answer. If you don't think it's a duplicate, please say why in a comment in the question, because I'm going to VtC.

Comment: That question which I reference mentions a different module of the library with similar behaviour, so I would say it's similar, not duplicate, even though the reasoning is the same it is not immediately obvious that it is so...